# PowerShell to call rest api url and parse a value from it

Tags: powershell

I have a text file rest_api.txt which has the JIRA issue URLs, like this

```
http://jira.tzgs.com/rest/api/2/issue/INF-1000?fields=fixVersions
http://jira.tzgs.com/rest/api/2/issue/INF-1001?fields=fixVersions
http://jira.tzgs.com/rest/api/2/issue/PRJ-6000?fields=fixVersions
```

When these urls are called it returns Jason file like structure. E.g.

```
{"expand":"renderedFields,names,schema,transitions,operations,editmeta,changelog","id":"54970","self":"http://jira.tzgs.com/rest/api/2/issue/54970","key":"INF-1000","fields":{"fixVersions":[{"self":"http://jira.tzgs.com/rest/api/2/version/15541","id":"15541","name":"NETBOOK 7.0.0","archived":false,"released":false}]}}
```

where, the "NETBOOK 7.0.0" is the Fix Version of this particular JIRA issue.

Could someone help me with a PowerShell script that will call each of these URLs and parse only this fix version value and write it to a file like this please?

```
INF-1000     NETBOOK 7.0.0
INF-1001     NETBOOK 7.0.0
PRJ-6000     NETAPP 1.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't write the code for you to get the information from all of the URL's (see SO's [On Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) question policy). But I will help with the parsing to get you started in the right direction. This is where PowerShell (version 3.0+) has a very nice `ConvertFrom-Json` parser.

```
$String = '{"expand":"renderedFields,names,schema,transitions,operations,editmeta,changelog","id":"54970","self":"http://jira.tzgs.com/rest/api/2/issue/54970","key":"INF-1000","fields":{"fixVersions":[{"self":"htt
p://jira.tzgs.com/rest/api/2/version/15541","id":"15541","name":"NETBOOK 7.0.0","archived":false,"released":false}]}}'

$JsonObj = ConvertFrom-Json $String
```

Then to return your fields you can access it like:

```
PS C:\> $JsonObj.key
INF-1000

PS C:\> $JsonObj.fields.fixVersions.name
NETBOOK 7.0.0
```